# Adjust the width of 2 divs using jQuery-Resizable

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, resizable, jquery-ui-resizable

I currently work on the following page:

[image: schema of the page]

divResizable has been modified by jQuery using the following code in `$().ready()`

```
 $("#divResizable").resizable({ handles: 'e' });
 $("#divResizable").bind("resize", function (event, ui) {
      $('#divContent').width(850 -(ui.size.width - 175));
 });
```

As you can see, I try to increase the width of divContent when divResizable gets smaller and the other way around. However, with this code, divContent doesn't always "grow" to the left side only, it sometimes extends to the right side to the irrelevant div, which doesn't make the resizing look good at all.

Is there any input for a more sophisticated method to let the width of those 2 divs correspond?

Something I could think of would be to set width of divContent to

```
(start of irrelevant - divResizable.width) == 850px
  ^ e.g 1025px          ^ e.g. 175px
```

How exactly would I do this using jQuery?

Comment: Any reason why your not nesting the divResizable and irrelevant div inside the divContent and floating them? Just asking to make sure you haven't overlooked an obvious solution.

Comment: Yup, since that isn't the complete site (the other elements are irrelevant for this question though) having them inside this div would unfortunately not work at all.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**[Demo](http://jsbin.com/omewec/1/)** - Your layout can handle this. If you wrap *`resizable`* and *`content`* together, you only need to adjust *`resizable`*'s width:

*HTML*

```
<div id="page">
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="resizable">resizable</div>
    <div id="content">content</div>
  </div>
  <div id="irrelevant">irrlevant</div>
</div>
```

*CSS*

```
#resizable  { float:left; width:175px; }
#content    { overflow:hidden; width:auto; }
#wrapper    { float:left; width:1025px; }
#irrelevant { }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and for even going through the work of adding a demo. But I'm afraid this is the effect I had earlier too, If I just adjust the width using a Textbox the calculation is rather easy on the browser, but I want to drag it dynamically using the mouse(http://jqueryui.com/demos/resizable/). Which is where the problems I mentioned in my original Question come to be.

Comment: I love when people are creating problems for themselfs. :) The example posted above uses **CSS to do the calculations, so you don't have to.** To make it resizable on mouse drag you would've needed **ONE LINE** of javascript: `$( "#resizable" ).resizable();`. I also love when people are too lazy to work out things. **http://jsbin.com/ikemu4/3/** ... see the "new" demo...

Comment: Calm down, Buttercup! Just making sure I get the highest possible amount of service for my Bounty. Unfortunately, `#content` will always go on behind `#resizable`, this is more than just "not cool" because it would require a revamp of all the background-pictures. Is there any way to accomplish what you did without letting `#content` go on behind `#resizable` ? Please check http://jsbin.com/ikemu4/7/ , red border. It shouldn't go this far to the left.

Comment: Alright Buttercup :), I forgot to add `overflow:hidden` to content. http://jsbin.com/ikemu4/9/

Comment: Is it just me or is the demo not working when trying to drag?

Comment: Google removed the jQuery UI CSS, I fixed the link. Try the DEMO now. http://jsbin.com/omewec/1/

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$("#divResizanle").resizable({ handles: 'e' });
    $("#divResizable").bind("resize", function (event, ui) {
        $('#divContent').width(850 -(ui.size.width - 175));
        $('#divContent').css("left",ui.size.width - ui.originalSize.width);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

try wrapping '**divresizable**' and '**divContent**' in a div with **width** set to the sum of the two contained divs

Comment: As soon as I try to resize, divContent "jumps" down into another row.

Comment: maybe I am wrong, but isn't it easier to have a **wrapping div** set to a specific width, have the **divResizable** set to a specific width, leave the **divContent** without a with set, or set it to **auto**, and apply the resize script to **divResizable**?